# A difficulty with JavaScript Array from a newbie

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript. From some tutorials I know in javascript there are two ways to declare the array.
One is like this:

`var test = new Array("apple","pine");`

or

`test = new Array("apple","pine");`

Two are like this,

`var test=["apple","pine"];`

but when i use this way to declare it:

`test=Array("apple","pine");`

It is still ok. why?

Comment: Wait a minute ... is this question about leaving out `var` or about leaving out `new`?

Comment: have a look at [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript, you may (and should) declare a variable using the `var` keyword, but it's not required. So any variable can be declared like this:

```
var a = 'abc';
```

or

```
a = 'abc';
```

But the first one (with `var`) should *always* be used when you're creating a new variable. Otherwise, you might be overwriting an already existing variable with the same name. An array is also a variable, so it too can be declared either with or without the `var` keyword. Then there are two ways to declare an array, and both do exactly the same thing:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

does the same as:

```
var a = new Array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

and the `new` keyword, in this case, is not required - as per the javascript specification. But it's usually used to indicate that you're creating a new instance of an object.

Comment: That is not actually true all the time, and leaving off `var` is a terribly bad idea in general.

Comment: Agreed, I should probably clarify that. Tried to keep the explanation as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes ok that's cool - leaving off `var` is a huge pitfall for programmers new to JavaScript, because it can make weird things happen that are quite difficult to debug. Scoping in JavaScript is confusing enough anyway :-)

Comment: Leaving out the `new` keyword can also create problems with any constructor (not only Array) cause `this` will not be bound to a new object but to the global object.

Comment: To clarify, leaving off the var creates a global variable (which is why you may be overwriting an existing variable)

Answer (score 2):

Because `new Array(...)` and `Array(...)` do the same thing (= create a new array). That's just how it's defined in the spec.

See here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.1

> When Array is called as a function
>   rather than as a constructor, it
>   creates and initialises a new Array
>   object. Thus the function call
>   Array(…) is equivalent to the object
>   creation expression new Array(…) with
>   the same arguments.

Therefore, these 3 lines are equivalent:

```
arr = ['apple', 'pine'];
arr = new Array('apple', 'pine');
arr = Array('apple', 'pine');
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you really should stick to the simple "[ ... ]" notation to create and initialize your arrays. Thus:

```
var test = ["apple", "pine"];
```

You should also be careful to use `var` for **all** your local variables. (Actually I'll go out on a limb and say that it's just bad practice not to use `var` for all declarations.)

Now, using the Array constructor without the `new` prefix works because that's just how the Array constructor is defined. In other words, if it's not invoked with `new`, it returns you an array anyway.  However, you really shouldn't worry about it because in most circumstances there's no reason to use the Array constructor at all.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is used to declare a variable's scope.

```
x = 'hello';

function y() {
    x = 'goodbye';
}

function z() {
    var x = 'how are you';
}

y()
alert(x); // outputs 'goodbye';
z();
alert(x); // outpus 'hello';
```

Basically `var` declares a variable to be local scope. It has no real effect if you use it at the top level of a script, but within a function it'll make the variable "local".